# Moving a small matrix inside of a bigger matrix in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, matrix, move

Let's assume that A is a 5x5 matrix of zeros:

```
>> A = zeros(5)

A =

     0     0     0     0     0
     0     0     0     0     0
     0     0     0     0     0
     0     0     0     0     0
     0     0     0     0     0
```

And B is a small matrix of ones (2x2):

```
>> B = ones(2)

B =

     1     1
     1     1
```

Now, I am looking for 16 different cases which represent matrices of `C1, C2, C3, ..., C16`

Which are:

```
C1 =                                

     1     1     0     0     0
     1     1     0     0     0
     0     0     0     0     0
     0     0     0     0     0
     0     0     0     0     0

C2 =                                

     0     0     0     0     0
     1     1     0     0     0
     1     1     0     0     0
     0     0     0     0     0
     0     0     0     0     0



C3 =                                

     0     0     0     0     0
     0     0     0     0     0
     1     1     0     0     0
     1     1     0     0     0
     0     0     0     0     0
```

... and finally `C16` is equal to :

```
C16 =                                

     0     0     0     0     0
     0     0     0     0     0
     0     0     0     0     0
     0     0     0     1     1
     0     0     0     1     1
```

As you can see, it is like smaller matrix (B) in moving inside of the bigger one (A).

Many thanks,

Comment: what exactly is your question here ?

Comment: @shrey How to move matrix A inside of matrix B.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could achieve what you want using `circshift(...)` on the appropriate rows and columns to [shift the values about the Matrix](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/circshift.html).  The example you mention is the example shown in the 'Move Matrix Elements' portion of the page with a 4x4 matrix.

Take for example

```
A = [1 1 0 0; 1 1 0 0; 0 0 0 0; 0 0 0 0]
A =

     1     1     0     0
     1     1     0     0
     0     0     0     0
     0     0     0     0
Y = circshift(A,[1 1])
Y =

     0     0     0     0
     0     1     1     0
     0     1     1     0
     0     0     0     0
```

From the Mathworks website, there is a builtin function that seems like it would do exactly what you want. The exact code to show the 16 combinations on a 5x5 matrix that keep the illusion of a small matrix moving through a big one would be

EDITED: so it now has a 5x5x16 matrix with the outputs called C

```
A=zeros(5,5);
A(1:2,1:2)=1
c=1;C=zeros(5,5,16);
for i=0:3
    for j=0:3
        C(:,:,c)=circshift(A,[i j])
        c=c+1;
    end
end
```

Which yields the output(NOTE output not edited)

```
A =

     1     1     0     0     0
     1     1     0     0     0
     0     0     0     0     0
     0     0     0     0     0
     0     0     0     0     0


ans =

     1     1     0     0     0
     1     1     0     0     0
     0     0     0     0     0
     0     0     0     0     0
     0     0     0     0     0


ans =

     0     1     1     0     0
     0     1     1     0     0
     0     0     0     0     0
     0     0     0     0     0
     0     0     0     0     0


ans =

     0     0     1     1     0
     0     0     1     1     0
     0     0     0     0     0
     0     0     0     0     0
     0     0     0     0     0


ans =

     0     0     0     1     1
     0     0     0     1     1
     0     0     0     0     0
     0     0     0     0     0
     0     0     0     0     0


ans =

     0     0     0     0     0
     1     1     0     0     0
     1     1     0     0     0
     0     0     0     0     0
     0     0     0     0     0


ans =

     0     0     0     0     0
     0     1     1     0     0
     0     1     1     0     0
     0     0     0     0     0
     0     0     0     0     0


ans =

     0     0     0     0     0
     0     0     1     1     0
     0     0     1     1     0
     0     0     0     0     0
     0     0     0     0     0


ans =

     0     0     0     0     0
     0     0     0     1     1
     0     0     0     1     1
     0     0     0     0     0
     0     0     0     0     0


ans =

     0     0     0     0     0
     0     0     0     0     0
     1     1     0     0     0
     1     1     0     0     0
     0     0     0     0     0


ans =

     0     0     0     0     0
     0     0     0     0     0
     0     1     1     0     0
     0     1     1     0     0
     0     0     0     0     0


ans =

     0     0     0     0     0
     0     0     0     0     0
     0     0     1     1     0
     0     0     1     1     0
     0     0     0     0     0


ans =

     0     0     0     0     0
     0     0     0     0     0
     0     0     0     1     1
     0     0     0     1     1
     0     0     0     0     0


ans =

     0     0     0     0     0
     0     0     0     0     0
     0     0     0     0     0
     1     1     0     0     0
     1     1     0     0     0


ans =

     0     0     0     0     0
     0     0     0     0     0
     0     0     0     0     0
     0     1     1     0     0
     0     1     1     0     0


ans =

     0     0     0     0     0
     0     0     0     0     0
     0     0     0     0     0
     0     0     1     1     0
     0     0     1     1     0


ans =

     0     0     0     0     0
     0     0     0     0     0
     0     0     0     0     0
     0     0     0     1     1
     0     0     0     1     1
```

Comment: Because Matlab has a builtin function that solves the problem.  If you look closely at the question it merely states that it appears that the 2x2 matrix is moving through the larger 5x5 matrix, not that the actual movement of the smaller matrix through the larger one was essential to the solution of the problem.

Comment: The OP wants an output of 16 matrices (in the example). My code outputs that and I don't think it matters if both of us had to use `for` loops whether you use indexing or `circshift`.

Comment: Using matlab builtin functions typically has better performance than custom functions that do the same thing, and I believe that the use of a cell array in this case is unnecessary.  If you edit your post I will get rid of the down vote so it can go back to neutral.

Comment: I agree that you using `circshift` is a better answer but, I think that since we don't know what the OP wants with these matrices, the cell array is the better option.

Comment: I will admit that I was a bit hasty with my down vote initially.  You make some valid points and the best solution is probably a combination of the two answers and some clarification about the question.  I believe that there is a `circshift` method that could be generalized for matrices of arbitrary sizes such that it could return all of the continuous combinations of a smaller matrix inside of a larger matrix; at least for sparse matrices, where most of the elements are 0.

Answer (score 3):

One vectorized approach with [`bsxfun`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/bsxfun.html) -

```
%// Get sizes and form size parameters for creating output
[mA,nA] = size(A);
[mB,nB] = size(B);
mC = mA - mB + 1;
nC = nA - nB + 1;

%// Get linear indices
stage1 = bsxfun(@plus,[1:mB]',[0:nB-1]*mA);    %//'
stage2 = bsxfun(@plus,[1:mC]',[0:nC-1]*mA)-1;  %//'
idx = bsxfun(@plus,stage1(:),stage2(:).' + [0:mC*nC-1]*mA*nA);   %//'

%// Replicate A to setup output; index into it with idx & replace B
C = repmat(A,1,1,mC*nC);
C(idx) = repmat(B(:),1,mC*nC)
```

Sample run -

```
A =
     1     1     8     4
     9     8     8     2
     7     9     5     1
     7     9     2     9
B =
     3     5
     3     6
     3     1
C(:,:,1) =
     3     5     8     4
     3     6     8     2
     3     1     5     1
     7     9     2     9
C(:,:,2) =
     1     1     8     4
     3     5     8     2
     3     6     5     1
     3     1     2     9
C(:,:,3) =
     1     3     5     4
     9     3     6     2
     7     3     1     1
     7     9     2     9
....

C(:,:,6) =
     1     1     8     4
     9     8     3     5
     7     9     3     6
     7     9     3     1
```

Comment: Thanks for your time. Your solution looks also great!

Answer (score 2):

I think a good way to do something like this

```
A = zeros(5);
B = ones(2);
C = cell(size(A,1)-size(B,1) + 1, size(A,2)-size(B,2) + 1);

for i = 1:size(A,1)-size(B,1) + 1
    for j = 1:size(A,2)-size(B,2) + 1
        C{i, j} = A;
        C{i, j}(i:i+size(B,1) - 1, j:j+size(B,2) - 1) = B;

        % Additional code here
    end
end

C = C(:);

% Additional code here
```

Comment: Thanks for your time buddy. Looks great, too!